# Show that $f(x) = \frac{1}{||x-b||}$ is continuous for $f:\mathbb{R}^n \setminus\{b\}\to \mathbb{R}$ by definition

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to show that the function $$f(x) = \frac{1}{\|x-b\|}$$ is continuous for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{b\} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is fixed and where $x \neq b$.

However, I would like to do this directly using the definition of continuity of a function, and thus without appealing to any of the theorems involving compositions of functions. Of course, we all know it is continuous for it is the composition of two continuous functions, however, as an exercise, I would like to try and prove it is continuous directly.

I am having troubles finding a value of $\delta > 0$ for a given $\varepsilon > 0$, only because I cannot manipulate the inequalities as much as is possible in $\mathbb{R}$.

Does anyone have any ideas for how to choose the $\delta > 0$ to show this is true? Or does it simply become too difficult and cumbersome to the point where one should just show it is continuous using compositions?

Thank you!

Comment: Note that if $~0 < ||x - b|| < \delta,~$ then each of $~|x_1 - b_1|, ~|x_2 - b_2|, ~\cdots, ~|x_n - b_n| < \delta.~$  This implies that $~b_i - \delta < x_i < b_i + \delta ~: ~i \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}.~$  This is a commonly used trick in this type of $~\epsilon,\delta~$ problem.  Another trick would be to artificially impose (in addition to the eventual $~\delta:\epsilon~$ relationship) something like $~\delta \leq \min(1/10, 1/n).~$  ...see next comment

Comment: Finally, if $~0 < r < x < s,~$ and $~0 < t < y < u,~$ and you are (for example) trying to identify a range for $~\dfrac{x}{y}~$ a lower bound can be constructed by combining the lower bound for $~x,~$ and the upper bound for $~y.~$  So, you would then have that $$\frac{r}{u} < \frac{x}{y} < \frac{s}{t}.$$  This is another commonly used trick.  Further, note (for example) that if $~\delta \leq (1/10),~$ then you have that $~\delta^2 \leq \dfrac{\delta}{10}.~$  This last point allows you to strive to find a **linear** $~\delta:\epsilon~$ relationship.

Comment: Additional point:  To show continuity, you need to show continuity at each element in $b_0 \in ~\Bbb{R^n}.~$  For any such point $~b_0 = (x_1,x_2, \cdots,x_n)~$ I suggest focusing on those values $~|x_1|, ~|x_2|, \cdots, |x_n|~$ that are non-zero, and examining the minimum positive amount.  Assuming that it is given by $~|x_1| > 0,~$ then I would include a separate constraint that (for example) $~\delta  \leq \dfrac{|x_1|}{2}.~$  This way, when you are focusing on the neighborhood of radius $~\delta~$ around $~b_0,~$ you will not have to worry about any of *those* components *changing sign*.

Comment: Re last comment however, for those components of $~b_0~$ that are equal to $~0,~$ you are forced to consider that in the $~\delta~$ neighborhood, such a component will take on both positive and negative values.

Answer (score 1):

The triangle inequality is a prominent friend to analysis students, but in my experience the **reverse triangle inequality** tends to get overlooked, or at least under-appreciated.

Fix $b$. For all $x$ and $y$, the reverse triangle inequality gives
\begin{align*}
  \biggl|\frac{1}{\|x - b\|} - \frac{1}{\|y - b\|}\biggr|
  &= \frac{\bigl|\|y - b\| - \|x - b\|\bigr|}{\|x - b\| \cdot \|y - b\|} \\
  &\leq \frac{\|y - x\|}{\|x - b\| \cdot \|y - b\|}.
\end{align*}

To show continuity at $x$, we fix $x$. The numerator can be made as small as we like (take $y$ sufficiently close to $x$), so to complete the proof it suffices to bound the denominator away from $0$ provided $y$ is sufficiently close to $x$.

A fairly standard idiom is to assume
$$
\|y - x\| \leq \tfrac{1}{2}\|x - b\|,
$$
which implies
\begin{align*}
  \tfrac{1}{2}\|x - b\|
  &= \|x - b\| - \tfrac{1}{2}\|x - b\| \\
  &\leq \|x - b\| - \|y - x\| &&\text{(right? $\ddot\smile$)} \\
  &\leq \bigl|\|x - b\| - \|y - x\|\bigr| \\
  &\leq \|y - b\| &&\text{(reverse triangle inequality).}
\end{align*}
(Exercise: Make a sketch to see what this says geometrically.) This gives the desired lower bound on the denominator
$$
0 < \tfrac{1}{2}\|x - b\|^{2} \leq \|x - b\| \cdot \|y - b\|
$$
provided $\|y - x\| \leq \frac{1}{2}\|x - b\|$.

(FWIW, we should strictly write $f:\mathbf{R}^{n}\setminus\{b\} \to \mathbf{R}$.)